# How to compile a C program without knowing the include files

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I have some example C code that I'm looking to adapt to suit my needs. Before then I'm trying to compile the example as it is. The C code contains a #include  reference, and I can find the .h file in an 'inc' directory. There is also a corresponding 'lib' directory. I am struggling to find the command line I need to compile the code.

So far I've managed to get to the following;

```
gcc -o amqsinqa -I/opt/mqm/inc amqsinqa.c -L/opt/mqm/lib -lcmqc
```

But it 'cannot find -lcmqc'. I've looked in lib and quite correctly there is no cmqc. How do I determine what -l option I need here?

The code looks fairly simple, there is the include reference;

```
#include <cmqc.h>
```

And the call itself;

```
MQCONN(QMgrName,&Hcon,&CompCode,&CReason);
```

If I omit the -l option from the command line I get;

```
undefined reference to 'MQCONN'
```

Which isn't a surprise. MQCONN is present in cmqc.h though.

Comment: `find / -name '*cmqc*'`?

Comment: What files are there in `/opt/mqm/lib`?

Comment: That just returns the .h files? Is it expected that the library file uses the same name as the header file?

Comment: Are you sure you installed the library correctly?

Comment: "Is it expected that the library file uses the same name as the header file?" No.

Comment: Not necessarily, hence the suggestion to see what library files _are_ present.

Comment: /opt/mqm/lib contains a range of .so files, for example libmqic.so, libmqmcb.so, etc.

Comment: There they are! I guess the library came with documentation telling you which functions are where.

Comment: if you don't know which of them to link, you can always check their symbol tables with `nm`, but should probably try reading the library documentation, or looking at any example makefiles provided

Comment: I didn't install the library, this is an existing installation (in this case IBM MQ) that I'm trying to write some code for. It is possible the files weren't installed, but I wouldn't expect the .h files to exist either?

Comment: Aha, yes a makefile might be useful, I'll see if there are any. NM seems to be bringing back a fair bit of information too, thanks. I'll work through those first.

Comment: It's also a good idea to see if the /opt/mqm package installed any man pages

Comment: IBM MQ should be pretty well-documented, and if you search a little you should be able to find some examples on how to build with it (including which libraries to link with). So time to go to your favorite search engine and start looking.

Comment: VTC on the ground that this eventually reduced to a request for documentation.

Comment: Is the name of the library something like `libcmqc.a` or `libcmqc.so`? `-lcmqc` means that the compiler has to load `libcmqc.a` or  `.so`.

Comment: The one I've identified as needed is libmqm.so, and so I'm using -lmqm. Problem is I get 'skipping incompatible ----- when searching for -lmqm', apparently the most obvious is a 32 bit/64 bit mismatch. Time to go library hunting...

Comment: Have you tried a tool such as Doxygen to parse the code and find out the dependencies ? http://gernotklingler.com/blog/open-source-tools-examine-and-adjust-include-dependencies/

Answer (score 5):

To try to help others, this reference is useful:

- 64 bit apps: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q028490_.htm
- 32 bit apps:
  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.1.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q028480_.htm

In summary:

- `-I` is for the product includes, which are (For Linux) usually in `/opt/mqm/inc`
- `-L` is the path to the libraries in your example which are (For Linux) usually in `/opt/mqm/lib` (for 32 bit applications) and `/opt/mqm/lib64` (for 64 bit
  applications)
- `-l` (lower case L) is for the required library/libraries,

and the actual library you need is either:

- `mqm` - server bound C applications (ie `-lmqm`, which links with `libmqm.so`)
- `mqic` - client bound C applications (ie `-lmqic`, which links with `libmqic.so`)

.. and a suffix of `_r` if you are building as a threaded application (ie you are linking with `-lpthread` as well, ie providing `-lmqm_r` or `-lmqic_r` which in effect links with `libmqm_r.so` or `libmqic.so`)

`cmqc.h` is the name of the main header file, and there are other `cmq*.h` headers you can optionally include as well.

If you are using the (stabilized) C++ libraries there's other libraries to include on the command line but that's outside the scope for this answer - see the referenced links

Comment: JasonE, after the changes made in MQ v7.1 to support multiple installations does IBM recommend one way or the other to use `mqm` (server bound) vs `mqic` (client bound)?  From what I can tell if you use `mqic` then you can only connect as a client, but if you use `mqm` you can connect either to a local queue manager (server bound) or as a client if the libraries do not find a local queue manager to connect to.  This second option seems to be more flexible since you do not need to recompile if you ever change direction and want to connect the "other" way.

Comment: JoshMc, great question. I deliberately didnt confuse the reply with that, as its a little more complex and the documentation around it is not very good (for anyone interested, see the Binding Options text under https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q095480_.htm) but you are right that potentially just linking with mqm can potentially satisfy your needs and act as either server or client app.

Comment: Thank you Jason.  The part I was specifically pointing out is `If the server library fails to load, a client connection is attempted.`  Can you confirm the outcome of the following hypothetical: 1. The full MQ server software is installed, 2. a queue manager called `QMGRLOCAL` is defined on that same server. 3. An app is linked to `mqm`.  4. The shell the app runs under has `MQCHLLIB`/`MQCHLTAB` defined pointing to a CCDT. 5. The CCDT has a entry for `QMGRREMOTE`. 6.  The app does a `MQCONN` specifying `QMGRREMOTE`.

Comment: I thought this would succeed because `QMGRREMOTE` is not local and would fall back to CCDT, but the comment makes me question this understanding because the server libraries would not fail to load.  Without testing I think it would either succeed via the CCDT or fail with MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR.

Comment: There's a difference between "failed to load" and "cannot find qmgr" of course. These days, if you install just the client packages (or use the redist client tar/zip file), then those include libmqm so that the library can always be found. I generally only use libmqm now, and rely on other mechanisms to select client mode. If the server is installed, then there's a CNO option or an environment variable to force client connections.

Comment: @MarkTaylor thank you for the response.  One article that influenced my understanding was Morag's "[IBM MQ Little Gem #30: MQ_CONNECT_TYPE](https://imwuc.socious.com/blog/ibm-mq-little-gem-30-mq_connect_type)" where she stated "If you don't set the MQ_CONNECT_TYPE environment variable, the mqm library will in fact try both. First it will try a local connection to the given queue manager name. If that succeeds all is well. If that fails, it will then try to use any client connection settings that are around, ..., to see if a client connection can be made to that queue manager."

Comment: I need to try it to see for myself but I thought this meant if the local queue manager was not found it would try client, but this also conflicts with the KC statement "If the underlying server library failed to load, a client connection is attempted instead.".

Comment: I did a quick test and `MQRC_Q_MGR_NAME_ERROR` was returned unless I set `MQ_CONNECT_TYPE=CLIENT`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the above for the guidance. Looks like I was missing a few things. This is what I did;

1. Use nm to identify which .so file contained what I wanted. This returned libmqm.so.
2. Move that into the -l command, which gave me;

   gcc -o amqsinqa -I/opt/mqm/inc amqsinqa.c -L/opt/mqm/lib -lmqm

   But it left me with a 'skipping incompatible' warning message followed by a 'cannot find' error message.
3. Most common Google answer to this issue was a 32/64 bit mismatch, so I searched for a 64 bit version of the same, which ended up being in lib64. So the final compile command is;

   gcc -o amqsinqa -I/opt/mqm/inc amqsinqa.c -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -lmqm

Answer (score 0):

You should review the gcc options, in particular the '-m' option,

If you want to build a 32-bit MQ application then you do:

```
gcc -m32 -o amqsinqa -I/opt/mqm/inc amqsinqa.c -L/opt/mqm/lib -lmqm
```

If you want to build a 64-bit MQ application then you do:

```
gcc -m64 -o amqsinqa -I/opt/mqm/inc amqsinqa.c -L/opt/mqm/lib64 -lmqm
```