# IBM Mq client linkage with existing cpp application

Tags: ibm-mq

I have installed mq client which is communicating with IBM MQ as server ,now I want this to work with my existing application as well , how do I link both , please note my existing application worked in local binding mode

Comment: Can you make changes to you cpp application?

Comment: First priority would be to not to make changes ,if there is no way then only we can make changes

Answer (score 0):

If you have an application that already works in local binding mode and you now want to use it in client mode, just set the MQ_CONNECT_TYPE environment variable to CLIENT, and set client information either in MQSERVER environment variable or use a CCDT. No changes, not even linkage, need be made to the application.

There is a worked example in [this blog post](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/morag-hughson/2017/12/13/ibm-mq-little-gem-30-mq-connect-type) if you want step by step instructions to try it out.

Comment: Or run it on a server with only MQ client installed,  MQ_CONNECT_TYPE environment variable should not be required in that case.

Comment: But what if my application is not reading these environment variables ? , Do I need some DLLs ?

Comment: @MohammedZishan your application does not read those MQ environment variables.  It is the MQ Client library that reads those MQ environment variables.   Just follow Morag's instructions and you will be good to go.  See here for IBM MQ C++ compile/link information: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=applications-building-mq-c-programs

Comment: Hi Morag, in the blog you state "If you don't set the MQ_CONNECT_TYPE environment variable, the mqm library will in fact try both. First it will try a local connection to the given queue manager name. If that succeeds all is well. If that fails, it will then try to use any client connection settings that are around, e.g. MQSERVER environment variable or a CCDT if one can be found, to see if a client connection can be made to that queue manager." I think this is incorrect, mq looks for the mq server libraries, if found it uses local binding if not the it will act as a client.

Comment: See this comment thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648727/how-to-compile-a-c-program-without-knowing-the-include-files/54653991#comment96104833_54653991

Comment: The new question led me to find this answer and my comments.   I think the blog is still wrong in the regard to it being based on finding the QM or not,  as Mark pointed out it is based finding the library or not. My test confirmed this behavior.   I haven't done a similar test with only client installed,  but believe it will work.