# QLoad utility to connect remote

Tags: ibm-mq

Is it possible to use qload utility to connect to remote queue manager.
I am not able to connect currently and has anyone tried and connected, if so how?
QLoad version : 1.9
I cant see any documentation on how to connect to remote queue manager.
I also tried set MQSERVER variable from command line before executing the command.

```
    qload -m <QM> -i <Queue> -f <filename>


QLOAD Program by Paul Clarke [ V1.9 Build:Jun 19 2012 ]
MQCONN on object '<QM>' returned 2058 QMgr name error..
```

Comment: What version of qload are you using?   Please update you question with the version and the command you are trying to run.

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ libraries are installed.   Can you update with the version and output of your command?

Comment: Which version of IBM MQ do you have installed on the machine you are running qload from? You can run `dspmqver` to find out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoke QLOAD as follows to use the client libraries.

```
qload -m <QM> -i <Queue> -l mqic -f <filename>
```

The `-l` flag allows to chose the library to be used, `mqic` vs `mqm`. The default if the flag is omitted is to use `mqm`. You can read documentation for a rather more up-to-date version of qload [here](https://www.mqgem.com/qload_download.html).

Alternatively, if you want to continue to use the `mqm` library, you can set the `MQ_CONNECT_TYPE` environment variable, as described [here](https://community.ibm.com/community/user/integration/blogs/morag-hughson/2017/12/13/ibm-mq-little-gem-30-mq-connect-type) to make a client connection using the `mqm` library.

Comment: Would it work without the -l flag on a v7.5 or later MQ install?

Comment: If you don't use the -l flag it will use the mqm library. If you set up MQ_CONNECT_TYPE=CLIENT then it will make a client connection using the mqm library.

Comment: That makes since.   I also believe if only MQ client is installed that mqm will work with client even if mqm is specified.  See this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54648727/how-to-compile-a-c-program-without-knowing-the-include-files/54653991#comment96104833_54653991).  Note I only tested with full install where it did not work with a non local queue manger.  With only client I need to check if MQ_CONNECT_TYPE is required or not.

Comment: Yes, the mqm library comes with the Client only install these days too. So you can just link programs with mqm and then choose at runtime whether you need local bindings or client bindings.